# asp.net mvc RequireLocalHostActionFilter not fireing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Im trying to implement the RequireLocalHostActionFilter  that Phil Haack did in one of his shows.

Its the ActionFilter thats checks if a call to a giving method is from the local host, and is registred in the global filters.

But my filter is not working, and I cant get my head around it.

So please, if someone has some free time to take a look.

My ActionFilter:

```
public class RequireLocalHostActionFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        return !httpContext.Request.IsLocal; // I need to test on the local host, so I reverse the logic.
    }

}
```

My FilterProvider

```
public class ConditionalFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    public readonly IEnumerable<Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>> _conditions;

    public ConditionalFilterProvider(IEnumerable<Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>> conditions)
    {
        this._conditions = conditions;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Filter>  GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        IEnumerable<Filter> result = from condition in _conditions
               select condition(controllerContext, actionDescriptor)
               into filter
               where filter != null
               select new Filter(filter, FilterScope.Global, null);
        return result;
    }

}
```

In globals.

```
        public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        var conditions = new Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>[]
                            {
                                (c, a) => 
                                    a.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.Equals("Online", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                    ? null : new RequireLocalHostActionFilter()
                            };

        filters.Add(new ConditionalFilterProvider(conditions));
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
```

I can see the action filter is added into the collection of filters.
And last my OnlineController, a simpel control, that I want the global filter to kick in.

```
    public class OnlineController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC! online";

        return View();  
    }
```

// thx for taking your time to read this post.
// dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My if statement needed to be reversed.

```
var conditions = new Func < ControllerContext,
  ActionDescriptor, object > [] {
   (c, a) =>
   a.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.Equals("Online",
    StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) * * ? new RequireLocalHostActionFilterAttribute() : null * *
  };
```

And I forgot to added the filter to the top of the controller.

// dennis